# How do I push a mobile app to a phone?

Tags: deployment

When I find a mobile app I like (for my Android phone), it seems like the standard way of installing it is to send me to the Google store (if I find the app on, say, its creator's web page). From there, I click "Install" and the app is then sent to my phone. I'm already logged in to Google at that point, so that part is transparent. Nothing is required after clicking "Install." The app then shows up on my phone. I have two questions.

First, is there a standard way that I can have that same Install button on my own web site and bypass the Google store?

Second, does everything I've said so far also apply to the iPhone and the Windows Phone, and does the answer to my first question also apply to those two systems?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: If you bypass the google store people that use your app have to flag a special setting on their phone to allow download of '3rd party' applications.  It's typically not a good thing for business, unless it's just something you and your friends want to use.

Comment: Having it pass through Google Play is necessary because by default you can't just install non-market apps (you have to specifically allow it on your phone), and because going through the store makes sure the user is informed of the rights your app will require before it's installed. I would not just click "Install" from any website and let it put anything on my mobile device it felt like putting there. (Apple and MS are more strict about what's allowed in their stores than Google, and neither usually allow anything to be installed that hasn't been approved by them for being in their stores.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661434/does-google-play-have-an-api